# Converting explicit $y=\sqrt{|x|}$ to parametric form

Tags: geometry

How do I convert $y=\sqrt{|x|}$, when $x\in [-1,1.5]$ to parametric form of $(x(t),y(t)), \,t \in [0,1]$?

Comment: Is $(2.5t-1, \sqrt{|2.5t-1|})$ what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It is almost already given in the question: to parametrize **any** function $\;y=f(x)\;$, with $\;x\in[a,b]\;$ , just take

$$\gamma(t):=(t,\,f(t)),\,t\in [a,b]$$

In your case:

$$\gamma(t)=\left(t,\,\sqrt{|t|}\right)\;,\;\;t\in[-1,\,1.5]\;$$

If you insist your parameter to be in $\;[0,1]\;$, you'll need to put

$$\gamma(t)=\left(at+b\,,\,\,\sqrt{|at+b|}\right)$$

and solve for $\;a,b\;$ and $\;t\in[0,1]\;$ . It's not hard, try it.

Comment: Nice downvote. Apparently some frustrations on the air again...

Comment: Thanks for the help!